# C# .Select() doing no such thing

Tags: c#

I'm working on a sudoku puzzle for kicks and giggles.  I have the grid set up in a 2d SudokuTextBox array (an extension of TextBox that sets up the box how I like it)

It then loads the 2D array with the text boxes and tags them with their x and y elements.

```
box.Tag = x.ToString() + y.ToString();
```

It then loads it to that location in the array.

I assign a key press event to the boxes for navigation.

```
private void KeyNav(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    SudokuTextBox box = (SudokuTextBox)sender;
    string tag = box.Tag.ToString();
    int x = int.Parse(tag[0].ToString());
    int y = int.Parse(tag[1].ToString());

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        y--;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        y++;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        x--;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        x++;

    try { Grid[y, x].Select(); }
    catch {}
}
```

Now I have checked the x and ys, the targeted element/control, and the detection of the key presses.  Everything is correct.

It only moves left or right, it does not move up or down.  If i change the x-- and x++ to y-- and y++ in the Left and Right key checks, it then moves up and down.

Keys.Up and Keys.Down is detected, yet the .Select() does not work!

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

EDITED:

here is the grid creation incase you were wondering.

```
        int locX = 5;
        int locY = 5;

        for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
        {
            locY += PointAdj(y);

            for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            {
                locX += PointAdj(x);

                SudokuTextBox box = new SudokuTextBox();
                box.Location = new Point(locX, locY);
                box.Tag = x.ToString() + y.ToString();
                box.KeyDown += KeyNav;

                locX += box.square;

                Grid[y, x] = box;
                this.Controls.Add(Grid[y, x]);
            }
            locX = 5;
            locY += Grid[0, 0].square;
        }

    private int PointAdj(int point)
    {
        if (point % 3 != 0 || point == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return 5;
    }
```

Comment: What is this? Winforms, WPF, ASP?

Comment: What is `.Select()` _supposed_ to do?  Have you run it in the debugget and watched the variables to make sure the code is doing what you expect it to?

Comment: Is anything logged in your actual code of `catch(Exception ex) {...}` (I assume sample shows empty `catch{}`  for simplification)

Comment: I see you are catching the exceptions. Is there an exception when using Left/Right? Is x parsed correctly? Do you get expected results if you hardcode x to 1 or 2 or 3 (for example Grid[y, 2].Select() )?

Comment: If the left, right, top, or bottom most textboxes are selected then it will have an invalid element for the 2D array.  The catch is to just ignore it, doeesn't need to do anything about it.  I have checked the old vs new x and y values they are all dead on, and should work.  .Select brings the cursour to the new text box.

Comment: By the way why do I have -1 on this post?  Kids these days!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is the issue.  Multiline = true;  This overwrote the up and down key events.  Turning it to false will get rid of that event and allow you to make your own key press when it comes to the up and down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

A buddy of mine found this on MSDN

"To handle keyboard events only at the form level and not enable other controls to receive keyboard events, set the KeyPressEventArgs.Handled property in your form's KeyPress event-handling method to true. Certain keys, such as the TAB, RETURN, ESC, and arrow keys are handled by controls automatically. To have these keys raise the KeyDown event, you must override the IsInputKey method in each control on your form. The code for the override of the IsInputKey would need to determine if one of the special keys is pressed and return a value of true. Instead of overriding the IsInputKey method, you can handle the PreviewKeyDown event and set the IsInputKey property to true. For a code example, see the PreviewKeyDown event."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

In case anyone else has this issue!